# PHP IMAP как корректно получать заголовки писем?

Tags: php, email, imap

Добрый день! Имеется следующая задача:

Необходимо получать письма (точнее их заголовки), которые отсылают менеджеры со своих корпоративных ящиков по базе клиентов.

Прочитал документацию PHP по разделу IMAP http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.imap.php .

Однако несколько вопросов так и не смог прояснить.

1. Если какое-то письмо пометили флагом "Важное" (этот флаг читается в заголовках), каким образом можно БЫСТРО и НЕ читая все заголовки всех писем, об этом узнать? Есть какая-нибудь функция, вроде "получить все изменения с такой-то даты"?
2. Как узнать, в какой папке лежит письмо, не сканируя каждую папку отдельно?
3. Что делает функция imap_subscribe? В документации написано "Подписывает на почтовый ящик", но я не понимаю, что это значит. Слушает события этого ящика? Где описывать коллбэки тогда?

Ткните, пожалуйста, в справочники/документацию/книги.
Спасибо.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-fetch-overview.php

Comment: Ваш ответ не отвечает ни на один мой вопрос.

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий. Среди массива объектов с заголовками как раз можно найти важные письма по элементу `flagged`. Но раз вам только важные нужны, то пользуйтесь функцией поиска http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-search.php которая вернет номера нужных вам сообщений, а по номерам уже получайте заголовки через http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imap-headerinfo.php например.

Comment: Спасибо! Imap-search с критерием "флаг" я действительно упустил из виду.

Comment: Спасибо! Imap-search с критерием "флаг" я действительно упустил из виду.